# Parsing Robots.txt in python

Tags: python, robots.txt

I want to parse robots.txt file in python. 
I have explored robotParser and robotExclusionParser but nothing really satisfy my criteria. I want to fetch all the diallowedUrls and allowedUrls in a single shot rather then manually checking for each url if it is allowed or not. Is there any library to do this?

Comment: Can I ask what robot.txt contains, and what you mean by parse the text file?

Comment: robots.txt is a standard which is followed by every sitemap support. Sitemap : To make our content searchable.

Comment: example : https://fortune.com/robots.txt  http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Ah okay that makes more sense now, maybe you should link to this in your question for others that are unfamiliar with this concept.

Comment: since robot.txt data is in `<pre>` tag, you cannot use html parse here, there is an alternate option `disallow = [ i for i in data.split('\n') if 'Disallow' in i]`

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox Sure. Thanks. I was searching for a standard library to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Why do you have to check your URLs manually?
You can use `urllib.robotparser` in Python 3, and do something like this:

```
import urllib.robotparser as urobot
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "example.com"
rp = urobot.RobotFileParser()
rp.set_url(url + "/robots.txt")
rp.read()
if rp.can_fetch("*", url):
    site = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    sauce = site.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, "html.parser")
    actual_url = site.geturl()[:site.geturl().rfind('/')]
    
    my_list = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
    for i in my_list:
        # rather than != "#" you can control your list before loop over it
        if i != "#":
            newurl = str(actual_url)+"/"+str(i)
            try:
                if rp.can_fetch("*", newurl):
                    site = urllib.request.urlopen(newurl)
                    # do what you want on each authorized webpage
            except:
                pass
else:
    print("cannot scrape")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `curl` command to read the robots.txt file into a single string split it with new line check for allow and disallow urls.

```
import os
result = os.popen("curl https://fortune.com/robots.txt").read()
result_data_set = {"Disallowed":[], "Allowed":[]}

for line in result.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith('Allow'):    # this is for allowed url
        result_data_set["Allowed"].append(line.split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0])    # to neglect the comments or other junk info
    elif line.startswith('Disallow'):    # this is for disallowed url
        result_data_set["Disallowed"].append(line.split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0])    # to neglect the comments or other junk info

print (result_data_set)
```

Comment: you are welcome. nope @Ritu, couldn't find which suffices your use case. May be you can extend it and build library.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, RobotFileParser can do the job, consider the following code

```
def iterate_rules(robots_content):
    rfp = RobotFileParser()
    rfp.parse(robots_content.splitlines())
    entries = [rfp.default_entry, *rfp.entries]\
              if rfp.default_entry else rfp.entries
    for entry in entries:
        for ruleline in entry.rulelines:
            yield (entry.useragents, ruleline.path, ruleline.allowance)
```

from [my post on medium](https://medium.com/@socrateslee/analyze-robots-txt-with-python-standard-library-9298be7477b8)

Answer (score 0):

I like to share smallest code.

```
sitemap_urls = re.findall(r'[sS][iI][tT][eE][mM][aA][pP]:\s*(.*?)\s*', response.text, re.IGNORECASE)
print("sitemap_urls", sitemap_urls)
```

Pretty easy to extract, where sitemap might in capital or small or proper case.

Please test and share your valuable feedback